# Azure DevOps / Trigger pipeline which provide dependency artifact on manual run

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new to azure devops, migrating from teamcity. I use classic editor, not yaml (sorry)

Let's say we have pipeline for common library: `CommonLib`

And we have pipeline which build a suite of tools (all of them dependent on CommonLib): `ToolsSuite`
On start of this pipeline we download artifacts from CommonLib.

The thing that `CommonLib` updated not frequently and we can save some time if we will build it only when it was changed.

In TeamCity I can set direct dependency and so when I **manually** trigger `ToolsSuite` it able to see if `CommonLib` was changed or no and rebuild if needed. In this way I'm sure that will get latest artifacts from `CommonLib`.

I want to have same in Azure pipeline and I'm able to set trigger on `ToolsSuite` pipeline for **Build Completion** to trigger on `CommonLib` build complete. But that does not ensure at all that `CommonLib` will be built by trigger during manual start of `ToolsSuite`, so there is risk that we can get *not latest* artifacts. To solve it - we can set `CommonLib` to start build when there is new pushed commits. Without this trigger we have a high risk that we will get old artifacts without any notice (unless build of tools will fail).

I just want to be 100% sure that `ToolsSuite` will get latest from `CommonLib`. And current approach in azure looks not safe from this point. If trigger on `CommonLib` will be accidently changed by someone we might get in bad situation with `ToolsSuite` use old artifacts.

Am I getting the logic of azure pipelines right ? 
Should I just put build of `CommonLib` as a first agent job for `ToolsSuite` and have only one pipeline for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in Azure Pipeline to trigger another pipeline on-demand in case it has unbuilt changes.

The Azure Pipelines way is to do what you have described:

- Configure CI for `CommonLib`
- Configure Pipeline Completion trigger for `CommonLib` in the pipeline of `ToolSuite`.

There is no way, apart from permissions, to enforce the CI trigger on `CommonLib`. This is easier to protect in YAML, as you can setup a Pull Request policy to require review  changes to the YAML file.

The Download Pipeline Artifact & Download Build Artifact tasks have a Branch and a Tag filter option.

And you can add a branch-filter to the build completion trigger:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, So if I want to add same pipeline for experimental branch and I do clone of `ToolsSuite` it will be copied with trigger to `CommonLib` for other branch and I end up with mixed branch build ? Can branch be a parameter ?